# For loop for increasing the number of neurons in deep layer in Keras

Tags: python, for-loop, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to implement a for loop in keras which iterates and increases the numbe rof neurons in the deep layers one by one. I have total of three layers. I also am trying to store the answers, the values of number of neurons and the MSE in an excel file. This is the code I am trying to implement:

```
def train_model(neurons):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(1, 66):
    dataset.add(Dense(units=i, activation="tanh"))
    dataset.add(Dense(units=i, activation="tanh"))
    dataset.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    return model
results = []
for neurons in range(1, 65):
    model = train_model(neurons)
    accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[1]
    results.append((neurons, accuracy))

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Neurons', 'Accuracy'])
df.to_excel('neurons_results.xlsx', index=False)
print("Results saved to", 'neurons_results.xlsx')
```

How can I implement this ?

I have tried running the loop above. When I run the code, It just runs for the maximum number of neurons i.e 65

Comment: In each loop iteration from 0 to 65 (range(65)) you are create a separate model and train it, and you always pass the same number of neurons to the first two layers (i), So is what you exactly want from the for loop or something else??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
def train_model(neurons):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    return model
```

Comment: yes, but in the range of 1-64 neurons